# Why does ipython kernel die when trying to access Google Analytics API?

Tags: python, google-analytics, ipython

**Edit: Ran it in python interpreter without problems, but running it with ipython always crashes.**

I'm trying to get data from the Google Analytics API into an ipython notebook following the [Hello Analytics tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py#install) with small modifications and some currently unnecessary libraries. However, every time I run that code the kernel dies without traceback / error message. Here's the whole code:

```
import argparse
import httplib2

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools

from httplib2 import Http

## API args

api_name = "analytics"
api_version = "v3"
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
key_file_location = 'path/to/keyfile.json'
service_account_email = "id@serviceaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

def get_service(api_name, api_version, scopes, key_file_location, service_account_email):
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(key_file_location, scopes)
    http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
    service = build(api_name, api_version, http=http_auth)
    return service
```

It's when executing the line below that the kernel dies pretty much immediately without any further information.

```
service = get_service(api_name, api_version, scopes, key_file_location, service_account_email)

foo = service.management().accounts().list().execute()
print(foo)
```

Any indication why the code doesn't work? Or are there better suited routes for accessing GA data from ipython notebooks?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Google2Pandas. It an easy to use module that works perfectly in the iPython notebooks.

https://github.com/panalysis/Google2Pandas

Comment: Whilst this link may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also note that [answers that are barely more than a link are subject to deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).